# In facebook api, not getting relationships_status

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

For some reason, I can't get `relationship_status` for any of my users' friends via the Facebook API.

1. I'm asking for the right set of permissions:  the scope is set to `"friends_birthday,friends_location,friends_relationship_details"`
2. I verified I have those permissions (checked via manual check of permissions for my app)
3. I verified I'm asking for the right fields.

   ```
   FB.api('/me/friends', {fields: 'name,id,location,gender,relationship_status,birthday'}, function(response) {...
   ```
4. I verified when I ask for those fields in the Facebook explorer, I do indeed get the `relationships_status` for lots of people.  (and I know I won't get it for everyone)

However, when I call it via `javascript`, the response includes everything but `relationship_status` for friends.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `friends_relationships` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions) instead of `friends_relationship_details`, since you are fetching relationship_status of a friend.